# Get Time from DateTime in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a table which contains the field "created". It is a DateTime type. I am getting the data using:

```
$this->MyModel->find("all");
```

I only need the time (12:00:00) from the DateTime (2013-12-27 12:00:00). In SQL it is very easy to do by using DATE_FORMAT() but I have no Idea how to do this in cake... I want to do this in the model by getting the data from DB and not one by one in the view using TimeHelper.

Comment: Seems like it would be better to do this in the view with the TimeHelper (as you mentioned) - is there a reason you want to do otherwise?

Comment: I provide the data using json_encode. I get the json data using JavaScript.. The solution would be to go through all the data array, change/add the time and then convert it back using json_encode.. maybe there is some easier/quicker way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a virtual field

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

    var $virtualFields = array(
            'time' => 'DATE_FORMAT(myModel.date_time,"%H/%i/%s")');

    //the rest of the class
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd go with this over my answer.

Comment: this is strange, it doesn't work when I use $virtualFields in the model like in your example. But if I put it in the controller like this, it works:  $this->MyModel->virtualFields = array('time'=>"DATE_FORMAT(created, '%H:%m')");

Answer (score 3):

In your `find()`'s options->fields array,

```
'fields' => array(
    "DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as created"
);
```

Comment: I'm leaving this answer, as it is still valid IMO, but I personally like using virtualFields better per answer by @Kai.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $query = $product->find();
   $query->select(['id', 'available_date']);
   $list = $query->toArray();
   foreach ($list as $datalist) {
           $final_list['available_date_new']['date'] =  $datalist->available_date->i18nFormat('dd-MM-Y'); 
   }
   print_r($final_list);
```